# Angular directive - third parameter is always zero

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am in the process of replacing an MVC HtmlHelper with an equivalent Angular directive. The helper renders a Font Awesome icon based on a couple of parameters. This works to a point, however the third parameter is always zero.

Markup:

```
<subscription-product-icon productid="p.ProductID" productname="p.ProductName" additionalclass="fa-lg"></subscription-product-icon>
```

Directive:

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [])
        .directive('subscriptionProductIcon', function () {

            var getTemplate = function (productid, productname, additionalclass) {
                var iconClass = additionalclass;
                debugger
                switch (productid) {
                    case 1:
                        iconClass += " fa-circle-o-notch free-subscription";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        iconClass += " fa-circle-o-notch standard-subscription";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        iconClass += " fa-calendar live-availability";
                        break;
                    default:
                        iconClass += " fa-question text-red";
                        break;
                }

                return "<i class='fa " + iconClass + "' title='" + productname + "' aria-hidden='True'></i>";
            };

            return {
                restrict: "E",
                scope: {
                    productid: "=",
                    productname: "=",
                    additionalclass: "="
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.html(getTemplate(scope.productid, scope.productname, scope.additionalclass));
                    console.log("test", scope.productid);
                }
            };

        });
})();
```

While the first two parmeters work fine, the third parameter

> additionalclass

is always zero. Can anyone explain why?

This is my first ever Angular directive, on day 1 of using Angular btw so I am no expert!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have defined additionalClass attr in directive as two way binding `"="` and then you are trying to pass a constant string to it rather than a variable.

Fix-

1. Change `"="` to `"@"` for additionalClass attr
2. Pass a variable to additionalClass attr same as other two

Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wY97r6bb2CTVfjH5D42C?p=preview) to see it in action

Hope this helps